# Can we force a div element to "wrap" by css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

(**Final solution below**)

---

I'm pretty sure it's not possible the way I imagine it, but there are so many smart, clever and gentle people on Stackoverflow, I'll give it a shot.

I have `container-div` elements which get filled with one or more "`child-div`" elements. The containers are more or less "virtual", actually they only should show which children belong together. Since I don't know how many child's are placed within each parent I cannot work with a fixed width. Those elements should be able to float to handle window resizing gracefully.

My goal is, to display the same amount of "child-divs" in a row regardless in which parent-div they are. My current problem is, that the `float` causes the whole parent-container to wrap, so the question is, is there any possible way to "saw" a `div`, like this:

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Does that make any sense ? Here is my current playground:

http://jsfiddle.net/5FXBu/

---

After lots of experiments together with **Gaby aka G. Petrioli** (thanks dude), I finally created this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/5FXBu/11/

Comment: Have you played with "display: inline-block"?

Comment: @Pointy: a little, but without much success. Open for any recommendation.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean - it's like you want the outer `<div>` wrappers to behave kind-of like inline `<span>`-like elements. I don't think I know how to do that.

Comment: @jAndy, oups.. hadn't seen you playground code.. checking that out..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `container-div` are just for grouping and have little effect on the graphical design you can just set them as `inline`. Setting the `child-div` as `inline-block` allows to pass some of the layout requirement of the `container-div` to the `child-div` (*margins mainly..*)

example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/pvWHr/

Comment: interesting aproach. Let me fool around with that a little.

Comment: looks very good. I guess with a few tweaks for my needs this could be it. Now I'm almost afraid of testing the cross-browser compliance, pretty scared of IE.

Comment: @jAndy, here is my attempt at hacking your code assuming that you need this more like an editor of sorts.. (*made some addition to the html as well*) **http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/5FXBu/3/**

Comment: @jAndy, ah yes.. IE will be an issue i think .. :)

Comment: IE8 performs surpringly well. That's just enough for the requirement. Very nice work.

Comment: @GabyakaGPetrioli: do you see a way how to create something like a "title-bar" for the wrapper class aswell ?

Comment: @jAndy i would make the `.wrap` to be `position:relative` and add another `span` in there with `position:absolute` to hold the title. something like **http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/5FXBu/6/**

Comment: @GabyakaGPetrioli: yes I created something similar. Also tried with css `content`. Works, but the "edge behavior" when wrapping is somewhat wierd. At least in FF and Chrome. Looks like the "title" span does not wrap early enough sometimes.

Comment: @jAndy, not an easy task for straightforward css.. but with service like dummyimage.com and a line of JS you can do this **http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/5FXBu/8/**

Comment: I like it. Unfortunately I can't use that external link in my context and I'm not willing to write a local copy of that :o) I'm sticking to the absolute `<span>` or `.wrap:before` with `css content`. Didn't find a really great solution for both so far. It looks like the browsers don't realize that it should wrap even when the element is off-float like absolute.

Comment: @jAndy, :( I believe it is impossible to imitate the `inline` rendering properties with non-inline elements. And inline elements cannot be made to fit/stretch widths etc.. so pure css is out..

Comment: @GabyakaGPetrioli: don't say that! It looks so close actually! But I'm afraid you're right. Currently playing around with some javascript to the rescue.

Comment: @GabyakaGPetrioli: this is my final version so far. http://jsfiddle.net/5FXBu/9/. The trick was to use `.wrap:after` instead of `:before`.

Comment: @jAndy, great !! (*although you cannot set a background to the title, it will not wrap*). Here is a version with a css counter to differentiate the titles http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/5FXBu/10/

Comment: @GabyakaGPetrioli: I've updated my question with (what I figure) the ultimate solution :-). Mostly based on your work, I hope you like that 'trickery' as much as I did (and do!).

Comment: @jAndy, that is a brilliant use of canvas !! I just might use that in the future .. It hadn't occurred to me how useful it can get.. Thanks for sharing :)